# is it possible to play two videos in same scene in cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

cocos2dx masters I want to play two video clips in same scene simultaneously. I create two layers and adding in to scene but video is always displays in full screen.Anybody can help me please?

Comment: Cocos2D is iOS right?

Comment: Never mind, I was thinking of Cocoa

Comment: I am working with COCOS2D-X which is cross platform works with ios/android/blackberry/bada/windows/linux etc. It is c++ 2d game engine by cocos2d.

Comment: On iOS AVPlayer can play two videos at once, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646235/multiple-videos-with-avplayer 

http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66 No idea about Android.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D will it work for android also?

Comment: no, that's an iOS API.

Comment: How do you play the video? Do you have custom Activity added to cocos2dxlib? If so, you can change the layout of this activity to have two VideoViews so each of them can play a separate video.